# How to increment a SQL entry during a SQL Update in SQLIite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I feel like this is a pretty basic SQL  question but I am having trouble searching for the answer.

Essentially the logic I want to write in my SQL statement is this.

When doing an update on a row instead of just blanking out the data there add it together.

so if I have a row `"9/19/13" | 0 | 1 | 0` and now I want to update that row with this entry `"9/19/13" | 0 | 1 | 0` I get `"9/19/13" | 0 | 2 | 0`.

My current update command looks like so.

`UPDATE entries(Date, John, Mark, Casey) SET (@Date, @John, @Mark, @Casey) WHERE(Date = @Date);`

I could easily do it in my actual code where I would retrieve the entry increment it then just do a regular update, but I feel like it should be possible to to do it with straight SQL, and would be cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
-- @John, @Mark, @Casey are set in advance

UPDATE entries(Date, John, Mark, Casey) 
    SET (@Date, John + @John, Mark + @Mark, Casey + @Casey)
    WHERE (Date = @Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

calling update is just setting the values in the db to be the values you pass in, not the existing value added (in the case of numbers) to the value you're updating with.

it would be much simpler to just increment the value before update as you already have it.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have the value before I want to update it. What I am trying to avoid is selecting this row `"9/19/13" | 0 | 1 | 0 `, pulling in the data, then doing an update and getting this in the end `"9/19/13" | 0 | 1 | 0 `. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: but if you're not actually changing anything I dont see why you're doing an update at all, is there a case where something is updated? if so what does that look like?